# jar package cannot be referenced in subdirectories

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I imported a jar package in the external libraries directory.Under the src directory, Test1 can reference classes from HelloJava.jar package and successfully run , but Test2 which in the subdirectory(com.cau) can not.

As the following pictures show:

picture1:
[image: picture 1]

picture2:
[image: picture 2]

Test1 code is:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Puppy MyPuppy = new Puppy("Jerry");
        MyPuppy.setPuppyAge(2);
        MyPuppy.getAge();
    }
}
```

picture3:
[image: picture 3]

Test2 code is:

```
package com.cau;
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Puppy MyPuppy = new Puppy("Jerry");
        MyPuppy.setPuppyAge(2);
        MyPuppy.getAge();
        System.out.println("123456");
    }

}
```

The class Puppy is in HelloJava.jar package.
In the third picture, the red color "Puppy" means Test2 was failed to reference HelloJava.jar.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: The problem is that your classes in that jar are in the default package, which means they cannot be imported nor used in classes declared in packages. So given `Test1` is also in the default package, it can use `Puppy`, but `Test2` can't because it is in the package `com.au`, and therefor can't use classes from the default package. Except for trivial code, you should avoid using the default package, and you definitely shouldn't use the default package for libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I really appreciate your suggestions and private messages.KNOWING WHY , I will move classes in default package to a new package.